# UseStaticFiles() throws error "Connection refused"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have problem with serving static file in asp.net core. I am really new to it. Just followed a tutorial from pluralsight and stuck here.

I have added index.html in wwwroot folder, and added dependencies for static file in Json, but still does not seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TheWorld
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
          //  app.Run(async (context) =>
          //  {
          //      await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
          //  });
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your Web app to serve a default page without the user having to fully qualify the URI, call the `UseDefaultFiles` extension method from `Startup.Configure` as follows.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

`UseDefaultFiles` must be called before `UseStaticFiles` to serve the default file.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-default-files